# Cannot invoke 'subscript' error

Tags: ios, swift, swap

I am trying to utilize a function borrowed from [this blog](http://iosdevelopertips.com/swift-code/swift-shuffle-array-type.html). Here is that function:

```
func shuffleArray<T>(array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>
{
    for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--
    {
        // Random int from 0 to index-1
        var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))

        // Swap two array elements
        // Notice '&' required as swap uses 'inout' parameters
        swap(&array[index], &array[j])
    }
    return array
}
```

However, when I try to declare it I get an error on the swap line - Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type '(inout inout $T6, inout inout $T11)'.

What is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `shuffleArray`'s first parameter needs to be an `inout` parameter:

```
func shuffleArray<T>(inout array: Array<T>)
```

An inout parameter means that the variable is passed by reference rather than by value. In other words, the function `shuffleArray` is making changes to the underlying object `array`, not a copy of it. That said, you can drop the return value of `shuffleArray` since by virtue of the variable being passed by reference, whatever you pass in will be mutated by the function.

Your final function should like this:

```
func shuffleArray<T>(inout array: Array<T>)
{
    for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--
    {
        var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))
        swap(&array[index], &array[j])
    }
}
```

Now when you pass in an array to the function use the `&` syntax.

```
func shuffleArray(&array)
```

Edit: you can also declare the first parameter as a variable and keep the return value:

```
func shuffleArray(var array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>
```

Comment: Awesome. That solved this problem at least. Now when I call the function a NSMutable array I'm getting a "Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSMutableArray' to type 'Array<T>'" error. Is that related or a different issue entirely. My hunch is it's the latter.